# TargetType property not found on DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ScreenViewModelCollection}">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate  x:Key="SomeKey" TargetType="{x:Type  local:RedScreenObject}">
                    <local:RedScreenObject/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

I have no idea why it can't see the TargetType property. Should be under Resources or ItemTemplate? I tried both it doesn't find it either way.

EDIT:
In order to get blasted by more downvotes ha ha it was in reference to this:
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4295316#4295316

Comment: TargetType is an attribute of the <Style> tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DataTemplate` only has a [`DataType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Use DataType="{x:Type  local:RedScreenObject}", not TargetType.

Comment: Oh right. I think Rachel made a mistake in her example code then thanks

Comment: That isn't working  
Only printing out the reference like so: WpfTut.ScreenObjects.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the TargetType under `<Style`